# Why there are so many "zzzzzzzzzzzz..." in chromecast payload type 127 RTP packets?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

As the picture shows: chromecast payload type 127 RTP packets from Nexus 5 contains lots of "zzzz..." comparing to from Ubuntu.

It looks like these "zzzzz..." is not so meaningful for screen mirror, thus I'm pretty confused why there are so many redundant content in packet?!

[image: Payload type 127 packet comparison : Nexus 5 vs. Ubuntu]

Comment: looks like padding to me

Comment: Could be, but why? Or could these bytes be used for some special purpose?

Comment: can you reply the request and modify those bytes in some way? you could probably find out if they're padding or not that way

Comment: I cannot access to the codes. Is this part open source?